# SOLVED Programmatically check if a VNC client is connected

Tags: vnc

I want to be able to check from with a python script whether a VNC client is connected. VNC Connect knows this and changes the colour of the VNC icon on the desktop. I want to capture this status programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Pi specific; on any system
`sudo systemctl status vncserver-x11-serviced.service`
should show status which you could parse.

`systemctl` is the place to start for information about services.

Comment: Thanks very much. Just what I needed